# Order of operations in the where

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-order-by

Here is my sql

```
SELECT * FROM Answers
WHERE QuesID = 1 AND OptionID IN (2,5) AND CONVERT(float, ISNULL(AnswerValue, 0)) < 300
```

The problem is there is legacy data that is string in OptionID = 6.  When I run the above query it gives me

> Error converting data type varchar to float.

I confirmed all data in QuesID=1 and OptionId IN (2,5) is all float data.  It seems like SQL is doing the math part of this sql first, is there anyway to make it check the OptionID before running the AnswerValue comparison?  Or am I completely off base?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really control the order in which SQL will "resolve" the clauses in your `WHERE` clause. I did some quick testing, and if there was a string value entered only for QuesId=3, it worked.

So, yes, as you posted while I was writing this, tossing in

```
AND isnumeric(AnswerValue) = 1
```

will handle this, as SQL appears to evaluate it earlier in its process.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` isn't guaranteed to run any earlier than the conversion, and doesn't guarantee safety. `ISNUMERIC('£')` = `1`, but it's still not convertible to `float`.

Comment: Giving you the answer since it seemed to work for me in the scenario I described.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, I just added ISNUMERIC to the SQL and that sorted that out.

Comment: The order of execution is not defined. I thought of using isnumeric, but isn't it possible to execute the other restriction first (thus giving the error again)?

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` isn't guaranteed to run any earlier than the conversion, and doesn't guarantee your safety. `ISNUMERIC('£')` = `1`, but it's still not convertible to `float`.

Answer (score 1):

A `CASE` expression will only evaluate its result expression(s) if the searched conditions match, so you might try:

```
SELECT * FROM Answers
WHERE
    CASE WHEN QuesID = 1 AND OptionID IN (2,5) THEN
        CONVERT(float, ISNULL(AnswerValue, 0))
    ELSE
        500
    END < 300
```

For more complex expressions, you may choose to use nested `CASE` expressions to perform more logic - oftentimes, this will result in you expressing all of the conditions and making the result equal to `0` or `1`, and then perform a final outer comparison to `1`:

```
WHERE
1 = CASE WHEN <Condition 1> THEN
        CASE WHEN <Condition 1, Subcondition 1> THEN 0
             WHEN <Condition 1, Subcondition 2> THEN 1
        END
         WHEN <Condition 2> THEN
        CASE WHEN <Condition 2, Subcondition 1> THEN 1
             WHEN <Condition 2, Subcondition 2> THEN 0
        END
    END
```

Where the two sub-conditions for `Condition 1` will only be evaluated if `Condition 1` is true (and similarly for `Condition 2`)

Comment: Be aware that order of operations is actually not guaranteed in a `CASE` expression.  [See Aaron's answer here for an example.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12945/1945)

Comment: @JNK - Ouch, nasty. There must be *some* way to do this.

Comment: I'd have gone with the case statement, but `isnumeric` worked for this query. (And that original answer got posted while I was writing, so I cut things short and didn't go over my assumptions. Oops.) The full-blown way to do this probably requires several steps and temp tables, or perhaps nested subqueries/CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to guarantee order of operations, and performance isn't as big of a concern, you might declare a table variable to store the results of your first two conditions, and then filter the temp table by your final condition. e.g.

```
declare @tempAnswers table (quesID int, optionid int, answervalue varchar(50))

insert into @tempAnswers
select * 
from Answers
where QuesID = 1 and OptionID in (2,5) 

select * from @tempAnswers
where convert(float, isnull(AnswerValue, 0)) < 300
```

Answer (score 0):

If and when you upgrade to SQL Server 2012, you can use TRY_CONVERT. It's proprietary, but it does solve the problem.

```
SELECT * FROM Answers
WHERE QuesID = 1
AND TRY_CONVERT(int,OptionID) IN (2,5)
AND CONVERT(float, ISNULL(AnswerValue, 0)) < 300
```